# Is it possible to get Android App category from Google Play?

Tags: php, android, html, web-services, google-play

Is it possible to get Android App category from Google Play? **Without using third party API`s like this: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/**

I see that there are non official ways with third party API`s  that can be used to achieve this, but i am searching for an official 100% Google provided future working way to achieve this.

Is it possible?

Thanks